# Can ReentrancyGuard be used in Proxies?

Tags: solidity, constructor, proxy-contracts, reentrant-attacks

ReentrancyGuard's `_status` is set in the constructor & we can't set it anywhere else: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/64e48203cecad94f02de9891ecdeed4d629c6dae/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol#L39-L41.

And in the proxy contract we **can't** have a constructor, only the `initialize()`, can the ReentrancyGuard's `nonReentrant` modifier be used in a proxy contract?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, we can use the `ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable` contract from `import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable.sol";`

Then simply call the `__ReentrancyGuard_init()` which set's the `_status`.

The modifier name remains `nonReentrant()`. This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Like @DiamondDust said, you can call `__ReentrancyGuard_init()`

But when you check the contract ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable, you'll see that the modifier `nonReentrant()` checks `_status` first.

```
require(_status != _ENTERED, "ReentrancyGuard: reentrant call");
```

Even without initializing `_status`, the check can succeed.